# tvOS: trigger a popover segue when a button is focused

Tags: swift, storyboard, segue, tvos

I have a view controller that has a button Show Detail. I want to implement a segue to show detail as a popover presentation segue. I control dragged the button to link to the view controller that contains detail information. But the popover will only be triggered when the button is touched.

Is there any way to trigger that segue when the button is focused and dismissed when not focused?

Answer (score 0):

I did not figure that out, so I worked around it.

Instead of having a segue, I made a hidden view in the storyboard where I want to have the 'popover'. When the button is in focus, I set `hiddenView.layer.hidden = false` and set hidden to true when the button is not in focus.

It does not look exactly like a popover since it does not point to the button though.

Answer (score 0):

If you give an identifier to the segue in Interface Builder, you can programmatically trigger it using performSegueWithIdentifier().